# iPad orientation misperformance

Tags: ios, ipad, orientation

This has gotten me extremely confused. I have one scroll views on a page nearly full portrait width. Inside this is 6 fixed height scrollviews, almost full width. The idea is that people scroll vertically to view the 6 scroll views and scroll horizontally within each scrollview.

My issue is orientation to landscape. I wish to expand to use the new horizontal space and reduce the vertical, with the 6 interior scrollviews retaining their height, however also taking advantage of the increased width.

If I let the iPad complete the rotation i get (based upon upper left = 0,0), the main view situations around -300, -800 and no change in size (as in still around 768, 1004). Additionally, the toolbar I have located at 0,0 now jumps to the bottom. I have status bar disabled, however every time I change orientation the status bar returns.

I have read every stackoverflow on iPad orientation. I have viewed about 10 tutorials / videos and this all appears so strange. Theoretically, I could modify my display in code with about a dozen line, however the rotation is just so out there that I am unsure where to start.

Any suggestion? OSX Lion, xCode4.4, iPad 3 iOS5
Regards
Chris H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have configured how you want all those objects to mutate when the orientation changes in Interface Builder Sizing & Layout inspector right?

In that inspector, you choose how each object in the view will mutate depending on orientation.  There are springs and struts that allow you to dictate where (or if) the object will be anchored somewhere or whether or not the object will be allowed to stretch its view.  The Apple Docs would give you much more information.

Here is a pic to show the inspector tab you need to use:
[image]

Comment: Ive had issues like this also. While your answer may be correct, please elaborate for those who may not understand how that panel of the inspector works

Comment: Not quite what I ment, A pic of the tab with description would be more use than this.

Comment: That is why I mentioned the apple docs.  Explaining how the springs and struts work is better learned straight from the source.  I am just helping to show the OP where to find the inspector and where to look for more info.

Comment: So, strictly speaking ElJay is correct, however I shall answer my question so that I can help RMDan

Comment: Use the outer red arrows on your main View object and it will rotate correctly. Pretty much anything you do with the outer arrows will attempt to maintain the distance to the containing object, however it will manipulate the size in ways you do not expect, such as not changing the width of the object, but manipulating the height. You need to decide what to control via the arrows. Internal height works, however external width on both sides did not. Experiment with using the arrows and when all combinations do not work, overrider it with code. :-)